# "if K is compact in R^p, then K x {a} is also compact in R^(p+1)" withough using Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: compactness

Should we prove the fact  "if K is compact in R^p, then K x {a} is also compact in R^(p+1)" ???

If so,
Can We prove "if K is compact in R^p, then K x {a} is also compact in R^(p+1)" by using only definition of compactness ( in other words, by only using the fact that K is compact if every covering A of K can be replaced by a finite covering of K, using only sets in A )...

(I am studying compactness in analysis(book: Elements of Analysis - Robert G bartle), not topology...
So It will be helpful not to use any topological knowledge if you can prove...)

Comment: The function $f:\Bbb R^p\to \Bbb R^{p+1} $ given by $f(x)=(x,a)$ is continuous and $f(K)=K\times \{a\}$,since $K$ is compact so is $K\times \{a\}$

Answer (score 0):

Have you been taught that in $R^p$,compactness is the same as being closed and bounded?
p.s. I didn't notice that you couldn't use Heine-Borel. In that case take any open cover $U_\alpha$ of $K\times(a)$. $U_\alpha\cap R^p$ will be an open cover of K.Choose a finite cover,and then at the most add one more open set to cover $K \times (a)$.

Comment: OP wants without that theorem

Comment: How does this work? you need to find open cover in $\Bbb R^{p+1}$

Comment: Yes,those sets whose intersection with $R^p$ are finite open covers of K.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a sequence of the form $x_n\times a, x_n\in K$, you can find a converging subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ since $K$ is compact, $x_{n_k}\times a$ is a converging subsequence of $x_n\times a$.